# target specific bootstrap tab from CodeIgniter controller

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I use bootstrap tabs, and I would like to open specific tab from my CI controller.
Code in my view look like this:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
     <li class="active"><a href="#tabs1-pane1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs1-pane2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs1-pane3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs1-pane4" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Now, i would like to process some data in my controller and when done, I want to open the Tab 3

I am trying with something like this:

```
 redirect(base_url()."hoteldetails/showHotel/".$hotelID."/#tabs1-pane3");
```

but the first tab is opened, instead of third tab.

Anyone can suggest some solution?

Regards, John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way;

```
<?php $tab = (isset($_GET['tab'])) ? $_GET['tab'] : null; ?> 

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs"> 
    <li class="<?php echo ($tab == 'tab1') ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url('hoteldetails/showHotel/13?tab=tab1'); ?>">Tab 1</a></li> 
    <li class="<?php echo ($tab == 'tab2') ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url('hoteldetails/showHotel/13?tab=tab2'); ?>">Tab 2</a></li> 
    <li class="<?php echo ($tab == 'tab3') ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url('hoteldetails/showHotel/13?tab=tab3'); ?>">Tab 3</a></li> 
    <li class="<?php echo ($tab == 'tab4') ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url('hoteldetails/showHotel/13?tab=tab4'); ?>">Tab 4</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Then, you should change each tab-pane, to have the active class too;

```
<div class="tab-pane <?php echo ($tab == 'tab1') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" id="tabs1-pane1">
```

Comment: It will take me couple of minutes to test the solution, I will post here as soon as I modify & test the script...

Comment: I forgot the class="" from the list item, I will amend the code.

Comment: I have jut updated the code, with an example I have just tested which works.

Comment: I will test it in a minute...I will post the outcome here...thanks for trying to help.

Comment: No problem. Does the tabs panel need an active class too?

Comment: I will see..i got bunch of php error now, php is complaining for undefined variable tab...i have to sort out that first...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56585/discussion-between-user2417624-and-craig).